# Syntax for Echo Command - ANSI Color Styling in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo

Running Bash 3.2 on a Mac. In terminal, I type in the following `echo` command and it returns text with green background and blue font:

```
echo "\033[34;42mThis is colored.\033[0m This is not colored."
```

I want to capture this command in a bash script, but cannot get it to display properly.

Very new to bash, so here's what I've discovered so far:

- I know that single quotes `''` means display it literally as written, which is not what I want
- It needs to be in `var=$(command)` format so interpreter knows to run it as a command
- I then display the variable by typing `echo $var`

So what's the proper way to write this command in a bash script? Are there any other crucial things I should know as a beginner of bash? Thanks.

my.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

teepee=$(echo "\033[34;42mThis is colored.\033[0m This is not colored.")
echo $teepee
```

Comment: Why not just set teepee to the string instead of using echo pointlessly in a subshell?

Comment: @123 I don't think I understand your question, but `a)` isn't the point of a script so that it can capture a group of commands for quicker/easier use in the future? and `b)` I am setting teepee to a string, but need the `echo` command for styling. Once again, I want it enclosed in a script to make it a variable I can call in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I needed to add the `-e` option to the `echo` command, which enables backslash interpretation (find more info [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo))

```
#!/bin/bash

teepee=$(echo -e "\033[34;42mThis is colored.\033[0m This is not colored.")
echo $teepee #works as expected
```

Comment: The man page of echo in OSX doesn't mention the -e parameter but it's correct, by default echo doesn't interpret the backslash.

Comment: You can use `teepee=$'\e[34;42mThis is colored.\e\[0mThis is not colored."` to avoid the unnecessary subshell.

Comment: @Dorian It is absolutely documented: "If the -e option is given, interpretation of the
    following backslash-escaped characters is turned on". This is the `bash` builtin `echo`, not the external program (which *doesn't* require `-e` because it processes escaped characters as required by the POSIX standard). The `bash` builtin is decidedly *not* POSIX-compliant (although there is a build-time option to make it so; `echo` is a mess and should be replaced with `printf` if you want any kind of predictable behavior.).

Comment: @chepner there was a slight typo (the `" "` didn't match) but nonetheless, this also did not work. You are the 2nd person to say this and I am a little confused. Don't I have to use the `echo` command to get the ANSI coloring style option? Also what are the dangers of having a subshell? And in bash, don't you have to have `()` to capture the output of a command? Is this what also makes it a subshell? Newbie here ^_^

Comment: No; `echo` just outputs bytes; the `-e` flag lets `echo` perform some work to convert byte strings like `\033` into a single byte, but `$'...'` does the same thing. Subshells generally require forking a new process, or at least creating a new context in memory, which is overhead that is good to avoid where possible.

Comment: `bash` itself doesn't color anything; the terminal that that displays the bytes output by `echo` has the job of interpreting some of those bytes as changing the color of the following bytes, rather than being displayed on-screen themselves.

Comment: @chepner how in world did you know that lol? but okay the subshell and styling makes sense. I guess this is something I need to 'turn on' for my terminal? Lastly, you also mentioned the 'external' program of the terminal window. Bash is running by default, but is there way to access this external terminal, basically exiting the bash shell?